# HTML/Javascript code to appear description

Tags: javascript, html

i'm a newbie here.
I have one question, do you have any idea to create a description appear in a box when mouse hover or click on an image? I have at least 15 image to view their description. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For displaying a description you'll need JS with a mouseover function, with some CSS attributes to change the format of the text.

This is better expressed in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/F6p2Z/2/

The JS:

```
$('.caption').on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).find('span').fadeIn(200);
    },

    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).find('span').stop().fadeOut(200);
    },
})
```

The span contains the text description. CSS will control the format of this.